# How to identify the correct primary actor from the use case diagram?

Tags: uml, actor, diagram

I have created a use case diagram based on a scenario, I identified 5 actors in total.

However, I am trying to identify the correct primary actor.

I am undecided between Team Leader and Maintenance Engineer as primary actor as they work pretty closely.

Comment: It seems to me you are modelling a business process using a use case diagram. I would suggest to use a UML activity diagram or a BPMN diagram instead. Use case diagrams are usually used to give an overview of the functionality of a particular software application.

Comment: The idea is to create a use case diagram from the user's point of view when using the web-based system, which is a requirement from the client to be added in the combined cycle gas turbine power station. I still have some doubts about which actor is the primary actor from the user's point of view using the system.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl is correct. I did not have a look at what you call use cases, just at your main question. You should not mix use cases with functions. There are quite a number of answers here on how to create use cases. I always recommend Bittner/Spence as the best read.

Comment: @The_Liner, if you want to "create a use case diagram from the user's point of view when using the web-based system", then the use case diagram shall only show the CSW, the use cases _inside_ CSW and their actors.

Comment: Perhaps in your case, all actors are primary actors. Note, that the same actor can be a primary actor w.r.t. one use case and a secondary actor w.r.t. another use case. For example, if a supplier interacts directly with the web-based system (it's not clear to me if he does), it is a primary actor for the use case 'Send spare parts with invoice'. If not, i.e. the supplier only sends a physical package and a physical invoice, then the primary actor is the employee who enters the information in the CSW and use case shall be called 'Enter data about received spare parts and invoice'.

Comment: If the CSW sends an email to the supplier that his package has been received, then supplier is a secondary actor. If there is no direct interaction between the CSW and the supplier at all, then supplier shall not appear as an actor in your diagram.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Your example helped me to start understanding how to correctly create a use case, I see there are mistakes in the use case, which I will amend soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two levels at stake here.

For a **whole system** or a whole use case diagram there may often be several primary actors:

> The primary actors are the ones for whom the system is built; they are the ones to whom the system provides sufficient economic value to warrant its construction. 
> - Bittner & Spence in *Use Case Modeling*

At the level of a **single use-case**, there may often be one primary actor:

> The primary actor of a use case is the stakeholder that calls on the system to deliver one of its services. (...) The primary actor is oten, but not always the actor who triggers the use case.
> - Cockburn in *Writing effective use cases*

In your case, it's even more ambiguous since you seem to have 13 use-cases split between 3 different systems (and some floating in-between): at which level are you looking for a primary actor?

### Hints, not related to your question**

1. reread the narrative carefully, and make the difference between the location where the users are assigned, and the software system they are using (I suspect there's only one system at play);
2. keep in mind that the use-case is not a user task outside the system but a goal that the user want to achieve with the system (e.g. does "Return parts" correspond to an activity in the system?)
3. keep in mind that some actors may correspond to other systems that shall interact with the system you are design (e.g. is FMS really in your scope or is it a supporting actor?)

Comment: at whole system level.

Comment: @The_Liner at the whole system level, `Maintenance engineer`, `Registered maintenance engineer` and `Team lead` are definitely primary actors (and you cannot select any single of them as sole primary). I'd even be tempted to see the `Store manager` as a primary actor on the base of the system's purpose: "a webbased system to manage the storage and installation of spare parts and the acquisition of new parts from the Central Storage Warehouse". But this can be debated. The `Supplier` is definitively not a primary actor (I wonder even if it is an actor at all)

Comment: The supplier is more a reactionary actor, I just included it in the scenario to give a complete look at how the system works as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

A primary actor is always the one that *triggers* the use case. Being external to the system under consideration he is the one to gain added value from using the system. There might well be multiple primary actors for a single use case. For the `Install` UC it would be both `Leader` and `Engineer`.

A so-called secondary actor in contrast is only involved in a way that its interaction is needed somewhere in the course of actions triggered by the primary actor.

Sometimes it makes sense to create an actor from which all primary actors inherit. You would give that actor the role name he plays. Just like in a theater. So in your case for the two "main" actors you can simply draw a generalization from `Leader` towards `Engineeer`. That means the `Leader` inherits from `Engineer` and thus has access to the `Install` use case. So bascially the `Leader` *acts* as `Engineer` (which pretty much makes sense).

Comment: I understand, so if I inherit the Team leader from the Maintenance Engineer, this means the Team Leader has all the use cases that Maintenance Engineer has. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is so.